# Advice on validation for a page that shows 2 forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

**What sort of validation options are there with asp.net mvc3?**

My page actually has 2 forms on it, and I am using strongly typed view data objects with razor.

1 form is for registration, the other is for login.

I guess the best way is to create 2 view data objects, and then have them as 2 properties on this mixed view data page.

How can I perform validation on these forms?

Is it by adding attributes to my models?  What happends if these form doesn't match up to the model 1:1?  (in this case I think it will for the registration page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Validation Groups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340751/asp-net-mvc-validation-groups)

Answer (score 1):

Blankman, if you have two forms, suppose that each form has its own action, in which case you could simply run the ModelState.IsValid validation check and the results appear on Validation Summary. It works for me.

Mix of your viewmodels or models is an option in case of strongly-typed views usage.