# Validate only ajax loaded partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a form with some controls. There is a button on the form which loads a partial view. Inside the partial view, there are two required field textboxes along with a button. And when its clicked, I need to display error messages only for textboxes which are inside the partial view, but not for the fields in the actual form. And when I click form's submit button, all error messages must show up.

After partial view is loaded, I am re-initializing the validation plugin as below.

```
$('#test').removeData("validator");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#test');
```

I tried using validation attribute described in below thread but its not working. Maybe it works for normally loaded views.

[ASP.NET MVC Validation Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340751/asp-net-mvc-validation-groups)

However, I can validate individually by calling textbox1.valid() and textbox2.valid(). But I think I am missing standard way of doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sundeep do want validate only partial view Controls?

Comment: Can anyone please suggest other options..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by  submitting  your partial view using Ajax.BeginForm()

```
//In Partail View
@model SomeModel
```

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeActionName", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "targetId"}))
     {

```
           @Html.EditorFor(mode=>model.FirstText)
           @Html.EditorFor(mode=>model.SecText)
           <input type="submit" value="save">
 }

//In Controller

public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    return PartaiulView(model);
}
```

here you can validate your Partial View 
NOTE: when you submit you form using Ajax.BeginForm you must specify "**UpdateTargetId**" where your result will be appear on View.

```
//In View

<div id="targetId">
   @Html.Partail("PartialView")
</div>
```

OR if you want to Redirect to another action if your model is valid then modified your action

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new {redirect = @Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")})
        }
        return PartaiulView(model);
    }
```

then in partail view you can invoke **OnSuccess** method of Ajax.BeginForm

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeActionName", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "targetId",OnSuccess="success"}))
         {

         }

<script type="text/javascript">

  function success(data)
  {
        if(data.redirect)
        {
            windows.location = data;
        }
  }
</script>
```

check both way which one is suitable to you.